# Использование NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Доброго времени суток. `NetBeans` при компиляции запускает все файлы `.java` в рамках одного проекта. Можно ли как то запустить только один .java файл? Выбирал "Выполнить файл", но все равно прогоняет все.

Вот я работаю со вторым файлом, при компиляции запускает и первый, хоть он и закрыт в редакторе.

[image: пример]

Comment: каждая программа имеет свою точку запуска метод main, и запуск крутится только вокруг этого метода. однако все же ты можешь скопилить класс

Comment: @dDevil, тогда получается правильнее создавать каждый раз новый проект?

Comment: @dDevil, обновил первый пост.

Comment: в списке проектов выбери нужный проект - правая кнопка - открывай свойства - выполнение - главный класс - нажимай обзор там и выбери класс, который тебе надо запустить

Comment: @dDevil, спасибо! Сделай как ответ, отмечу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Каждая программа имеет свою точку запуска **главный класс** с методом `main`, с которого запускается **главный поток** приложения. Если же в приложении имеются несколько таких точек, то главный класс можно указать явно несколькими способами. 
Для старта подойдет смена главного класса на уровне IDE.

Чтобы выбрать главный класс для приложения с несколькими классами, содержащих стартовый метод `main`, в IDE NetBeans нужно:

1. Выбрать проект в списке и нажать на **правую кнопку мыши**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Высветится контекстное меню, там выбери *Свойства*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Далее откроется окошко *Свойств*, там перейди в *Выполнение*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Далее в пункте *Главный класс* имеется кнопка **Обзор**, на ней и нажми, и выбери нужный тебе класс. Зафиксируй кнопкой **Выбрать главный класс** и нажми **Ок**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Готово!